# MLE application with gekko in python

Tags: optimization, python, minimax

I want to implement **MLE (Maximum likelihood estimation)** with `gekko` package in python. Suppose that we have a `DataFrame` that contains two columns: ['Loss', 'Target'] and its length is equal to 500.
First we have to import packages that we need:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Then we simply create the `DataFrame` like this:

```
My_DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"Loss":np.linspace(-555.795 , 477.841 , 500) , "Target":0.0})
My_DataFrame = My_DataFrame.sort_values(by=["Loss"] , ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
My_DataFrame
```

It going to be look like this:
[image]

**Some components of [‘Target’] column** should be calculated with a formula that I wrote it right down below in the picture(and the rest of them remains zero. I explained more in continue, please keep reading) so you can see it perfectly. Two main elements of formula are ‘Kasi’ and ‘Betaa’. I want to find best value for them that maximize sum of `My_DataFrame[‘Target’]`. So you got the idea and what is going to happen!

[image]

Now let me show you how I wrote the code for this purpose. First I define my **objective function:**

```
def obj_function(Array):
    """
    [Purpose]:
        + it will calculate each component of My_DataFrame["Target"] column! so the i can maximize sum(My_DataFrame["Target"]) and find best 'Kasi' and 'Betaa' for it!
    
    [Parameters]:
        + This function gets Array that contains 'Kasi' and 'Betaa'.
        Array[0] represents 'Kasi' and Array[1] represents 'Betaa'

    [returns]:
        + returns a pandas.series.
        actually it returns new components of My_DataFrame["Target"]
    """
    # in following code if you don't know what is `qw`, just look at the next code cell right after this cell (I mean next section).
    # in following code np.where(My_DataFrame["Loss"] == item)[0][0] is telling me the row's index of item. 
    for item in My_DataFrame[My_DataFrame["Loss"]>160]['Loss']:
        My_DataFrame.iloc[np.where(My_DataFrame["Loss"] == item)[0][0] , 1] = qw.log10((1/Array[1])*(  1 + (Array[0]*(item-160)/Array[1])**( (-1/Array[0]) - 1 )))

    return My_DataFrame["Target"]
```

if you got confused what's happening in `for loop` in `obj_function` function, check picture bellow, it contains a brief example! and if not, skip this part :

[image]

Then just we need to go through optimization. I use `gekko` package for this purpose. **Note that** I want to find best values of ‘Kasi’ and ‘Betaa’ so I have two main variables and I don’t have any kind of constraints!
So let’s get started:

```
# i have 2 variables : 'Kasi' and 'Betaa', so I put nd=2
nd = 2
qw = GEKKO()

# now i want to specify my variables ('Kasi'  and 'Betaa') with initial values --> Kasi = 0.7 and Betaa = 20.0
x = qw.Array(qw.Var , nd , value = [0.7 , 20])
# So i guess now x[0] represents 'Kasi' and x[1] represents 'Betaa'

qw.Maximize(np.sum(obj_function(x)))
```

And then when I want to solve the optimization with `qw.solve()`:

```
qw.solve()
```

But i got this error:

> Exception: This steady-state IMODE only allows scalar values.

How can I fix this problem?